# How to define a context bound with a higher kinded Type (Type Constructor)

Tags: scala, generics, types, higher-kinded-types, context-bound

I have tried the following

```
def test[Option[T]: Ordering](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

but does not work ? Any idea what's the issue ?

**EDIT**

This of course works

```
def test[T](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) (implicit ev: Ordering[Option[T]]) = {
  ev.compare(value1, value2)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really insist on using a context bound you can write a type lambda:

```
def test[T: ({type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]})#L](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

Or with the [kind-projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector) plugin you should be able to make this a bit cleaner:

```
def test[T: Lambda[x => Ordering[Option[x]]]](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

Comment: Ok will get back to study type lambda i guess. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you write `def test[Option[T]: Ordering]...` the `Option` doesn't refer to `scala.Option`, it's a new type parameter (you can denote it `Option` or `F` whatever). So

```
def test[Option[T]: Ordering](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

is actually

```
def test[F[_]: Ordering](value1: F[T], value2: F[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[F[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

aka

```
def test[F[_]](value1: F[T], value2: F[T])(implicit ev: Ordering[F]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[F[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

This does't compile because `T` is not defined and `Ordering[F]` doesn't make sense. What would compile is

```
def test[F[_], T](value1: F[T], value2: F[T])(implicit ev: Ordering[F[T]]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[F[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

I would recomment to switch on `scalacOptions += "-Xlint:type-parameter-shadow"`.