# Type Lambda on context bound and the role of type alias

Tags: scala, implicit, type-alias, type-constructor

I had to write a context bound for Ordering[Option[T]]

it turns out that the solution was

```
def test[T: ({type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]})#L](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

see [How to define a context bound with a higher kinded Type (Type Constructor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922959/how-to-define-a-context-bound-with-a-higher-kinded-type-type-constructor/63926624#63926624)

So played with type lambda a little to understand better, leading me to write the version without type lambda:

```
type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]

def testN[T: L](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  implicitly[L[T]].compare(value1, value2)
}
```

Many example of the use of Type lambda are for type constructor with 2 parameters such MAP[K,V].

In this case we do not have that problem.

So i just wonder, why not having something like this

```
def test[T: Ordering[Option]](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = {
  val e = implicitly(Ordering[Option[T]].compare(value1, value2))
}
```

obviously it does not work. I think I understood the all point, there is no type constructor `Ordering[Option[_]]` defined.

What we have in ordering is:

```
trait OptionOrdering[T] extends Ordering[Option[T]] {
    def optionOrdering: Ordering[T]
    def compare(x: Option[T], y: Option[T]) = (x, y) match {
      case (None, None)       => 0
      case (None, _)          => -1
      case (_, None)          => 1
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) => optionOrdering.compare(x, y)
    }
  }
  implicit def Option[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[Option[T]] =
    new OptionOrdering[T] { val optionOrdering = ord }
```

As it stands `Ordering[Option[T]]` in the definition above, is `Ordering[Option[T]] forSome {type T}` akka Existential, therefore a proper type, and not a type constructor.

So if i am correct what we do here:

```
({type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]})#L
```

or here:

```
type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]
```

is defining a Type Constructor `Ordering[Option[_]]`.

Question 1:

1 - is my understanding correct ? is that what the Type Lambda does here ?

2 - I'm a bit confused here, so type alias is something that allows you to create type constructor out of the composition of other type constructors. In a sense i am trying to understand the formal role of type alias with type variable.

```
scala> type e0 = Ordering[Option[_]]
defined type alias e0

scala> :kind -v e0
e0's kind is A
*
This is a proper type.
```

```
scala> type e1[w] = Ordering[Option[w]]
defined type alias e1

scala> :kind -v e1
e1's kind is F[A]
* -> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.

scala>
```

Comment: So `[X : F]` is expanded as `implicit ev: F[X]` - `Ordering[Option]` is not type constructor _(it does not look like `F[_]`)_ - the type lambda creates a new type `L[X] = Ordering[Option[X]]` which is a type constructor that looks like `F[_]` - A type alias is just a alias, a new name, to a new type; which in turn can be used to create aliases for type constructor, or even higher kinded types.

Comment: I think the type alias does a little more than just renaming espcially when it takes a type variable. I mean how can you create the type constructor ```Ordering[Option[_]]`` without the type alias ?

Comment: `Ordering[Option[_]]` is not a type constructor.

Comment: `type L[X] = Ordering[Option[X]]` is just an alias for a type constructor. It is not doing anything else, the same way the type lambda is not doing anything else than exactly this but without creating a new alias.

Comment: I guess my point is, given how Ordering is defined which is `Trait Ordering[T]`, if it was not for the type alias, how else can you create the type constructor ```Ordering[Option[X]]``` or even express it ......

Comment: Not sure what your point is, you need a type constructor _(let's call it `L`)_ that takes another type _(let's call it `X`)_ that is equal to `Ordering[Option[X]]`. Is not that different to writing equations in algebra. The language just need to provide a way to express such _"type function"_, and it turns out that such way is a type alias or a type lambda. The language could _(and IIRC **Dotty** wiil)_ provide a syntax like `X => Ordering[Option[X]]` to express that.

Comment: I think you just answer my question. Sorry if i was a bit confusing. That's precisely why i came here because i was confused. I never thought about type alias as something that sophisticated. I though it was just aliasing stuff, but no as you said above it does more: it allows you to express "type function". I needed something formal about it, something that name clearly what type alias can do. It felt like aliasing does not encompass the all functionality.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It will use arrow with two hats `=>>` like so `[X] =>> Ordering[Option[X]]`

Comment: BTW now the term type lambda makes total sense :)

Comment: "type function" is def better than type alias. They should rename the construct too.

Comment: Still for me is just an alias a new name, the same way `y = f(x) = x + 1` here `f` is just a new name for the expression `x + 1`.

Comment: I hear u. So it is preference I guess. In any case, your statement with type function did it for me, so thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous type constructor

```
({type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]})#L
```

is to named type constructor

```
type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]
```

what anonymous (value) constructor

```
(x: Int) => x + 1
```

is to named (value) constructor

```
val f = (x: Int) => x + 1
```

for example

```
scala> lazy val v: (({type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]})#L)[Int] = ???
lazy val v: scala.math.Ordering[Option[Int]] // unevaluated

scala> lazy val v: L[Int] = ???
lazy val v: L[Int] // unevaluated

scala> lazy val v = ((x: Int) => x + 1)(41)
lazy val v: Int // unevaluated

scala> lazy val v = f(41)
lazy val v: Int // unevaluated
```

In Scala 3 (Dotty) you will be able to replace the ["atrocity"](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/2041#issuecomment-283075876)

> There's less need for kind projector in dotty anyway because we have
> native type lambdas instead of the atrocity involving structural
> types.

with beautiful type lambda syntax

```
Starting dotty REPL...
scala> lazy val v: (({type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]})#L)[Int] = ???
lazy val v: Ordering[Option[Int]]

scala> lazy val v: ([x] =>> Ordering[Option[x]])[Int] = ???
lazy val v: Ordering[Option[Int]]
```

The context bound syntax

```
def test[T: ({type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]})#L](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T]) = ???
```

is equivalent to

```
def test[T](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T])(implicit ev: (({type L[x] = Ordering[Option[x]]})#L)[T]) = ???
```

which simplifies to

```
def test[T](value1: Option[T], value2: Option[T])(implicit ev: Ordering[Option[T]]) = ???
```